# VSCode snippet: How to apply more than one transformation to variable

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

Similarly to some VSCode extensions, I want to create a snippet that would allow me to read the filename and transform it twice:

- Capitalize its first letter
- Convert it to camelcase

So if my filename is `my-filename.tsx` the snippet would return `MyFilename`

I can do one of them at a time, with this:

```json
{
  "My Snippet": {
    "prefix": "snippet",
    "body": [
      "${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.)/${1:/capitalize}/}",
    ]
  }
}
```

and

```json
{
  "My Snippet": {
    "prefix": "snippet",
    "body": [
      "${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/camelcase}/}",
    ]
  }
}
```

But is it possible to chain both transformations and apply them at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```json
"My Snippet": {
    "prefix": "snippet",
    "body": [
        "${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.)(.*)/${1:/capitalize}${2:/camelcase}/}",
    ]
}
```

It just captures the rest of your variable and camelCases it.

But doesn't this simpler version do what you want:

```
"${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/pascalcase}/}",
```

Comment: Oh dear, I completely missed the purpose of `camelcase`. Thanks a lot, both do what I want but your first snippet approach will for sure help me out in the future for chaining transformations. Thanks!